# ./zkServer.sh status Error contacting service. It is probably not running

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I have installed zookeeper 3.4.9 version

and my `zoo.cfg` file configuration is as following

```
initLimit=10

syncLimit=5

dataDir=/usr/local/zookeeper/

clientPort=2181

DataLogDir=/usr/local/log/

server.1=hadoop-master:2888:3888

server.2=hadoop-slave-1:2889:3889

server.3=hadoop-slave-2:2890:3890
```

and ofcourse I have initiated `myid` file under `/usr/local/zookeeper/data/myid` in three nodes

and it contains the value 1 in hadoop-master server 
and 2 in hadoop-slave-1

and 3 in hadoop-slave-2

my slaves file is as following

```
hadoop-slave-1

hadoop-slave-2

hadoop-master
```

i have issued the command `./zkServer.sh start` in all three nodes 
and it gives me the out put

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default

Using config: /usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg

Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

but issuing the command `./zkServer.sh status`

gives me the output

```
Using config: /usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg

Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

why am i getting this output?

and `jps` command doesn't view

```
QuorumPeerMain
```

my `.bashrc` file is

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java-1.7.0/

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native

export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop
/lib/native"

export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop/

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
```

Comment: The `myid` file must be created under `/usr/local/zookeeper/`.

Comment: myid file in three nodes is located under /usr/local/zookeeper/data/myid

Comment: and /usr/local is the same path where hadoop locates

Comment: that's true my datadir in zoocfg had to bee /usr/local/zookeeper/data  i updeted it and the status of hadoop-master was leader and for hadoop-slave-1 was follower and for hadoop-slave-2 was follower  thanks very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zookeeper: It is probably not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909191/zookeeper-it-is-probably-not-running)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Zookeeper servers are not able to find their `myid` file under the `dataDir`.
Here the `dataDir` is set as `/usr/local/zookeeper/`, Create the `myid` files directly under the defined `dataDir`.

Restart Zookeeper servers after making the changes.

Answer (score 15):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29950279/6419332

You can easily debug it by  `zkServer.sh start-foreground`

zkServer.sh start-foreground makes it run out of demon mode!!!

Comment: Good one, pave the way to troubleshoot the issue on their way

Answer (score 0):

it's may be firewall or selinux they need to be turned off or allow for zookeeper